# Call hyperlink (tel:), number blank when called via javascript

Tags: javascript, href, tel

I have a simple wordpress navbar where I wanted to include a `tel:` link to automatically call the company's website.

Due to milions of issues with storing a `<a>` link inside the navbar I've opted for a `<button>` and added JS code to perform the redirecting.

```
document.querySelector('.btn--call').addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.open('tel:' + this.innerText, '_self'); //same effect for using `_system`)
    });
```

The problem is when I click the button I get redirected to the phone page but the number I'm calling is blank.
The variable retrieved is proper because console logging `this.innerText` prints the expected value.
The issue is also not with the website because I have a `<a href="tel:...>` in some other spot and it works like a charm.

I've tried to use `window.location.href='tel:' + this.innerText;` but the effect was the same.

Is there any way I could make the number properly parse without having to change it to `<a>`?

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I'm not familiar with Wordpress that intricately, what's the problems with using links in the navbar? Isn't that where links are supposed to go?

Comment: It generally is. The problems start when you want one of the links to be an absolute positioned block with button styling.

WP is nice but it generally keeps a strong grip on the styles they apply

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is accessing the element via target, instead of `this` on the event handler.

```
document.querySelector('.btn--call').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        location.href = 'tel:' + e.target.innerText;
    });
```

Comment: Nope. Same effect. `e.target` and `this` are basically the same objects, unless one's using arrow functiions, I guess.

Thanks for the feedback tho!

Comment: @aln447 did you use my exact code because I had a typo in the `location.href`?

Comment: NOpe. I only used the ending party. Now I've tried it with `location.href` instead of `window.location.href`. Same result unfortunately